# query to get date overlaping

Tags: python, django

I have a `model` named `Company_Position_Person` that determine each person works in a company with specified position between `startDate` and `endDate`:

```
class Company_Position_Person(models.Model):
    company_position=models.ForeignKey(Company_Position)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person)
    startDate=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    endDate=models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Now I want to find the List of colleagues of a specific person based on date overlapping.I mean find out which persons works at this company at the same time that a specific person works.For example I work in company at `startDate=2012-01-01` - `endDate=2012-21-12`.Another person that works at the same company at `startDate=2012-08-01` - `endDate=2013-21-12` is a colleague of me at this time.
I found out that [custome managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) can be useful but I don't know how to find out overlapping while running query and how to pass `startDate` and `endDate` of specific person to the manager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/325939/298479 is the "algorithm" you need to check if the two date ranges overlap.

Comment: tnx,I will check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are 4 cases for Overlaping and 2 for no overlaping:

```
......********.......   Source User
........****.........   Target User Overlaping
....*****............   Target User Overlaping
..........*******....   Target User Overlaping
....************.....   Target User Overlaping

......********.......   Source User
..**.................   Target User Not Overlaping
................**...   Target User Not Overlaping
```

No overlaping when `taget_end_date < source_begin_date` or `target_begin_date > source_end_date`.
Then **overlaping** where:

```
NOT (taget_end_date < source_begin_date or target_begin_date > source_end_date )
```

That is the equal than:

```
   not (taget_end_date < source_begin_date ) 
 and 
   not( target_begin_date > source_end_date )
```

That equals

```
 taget_end_date >= source_begin_date  and  target_begin_date <= source_end_date
```

For your code:

```
source = Company_Position_Person.objects.get( pk = 12 )
targets = Company_Position_Person.filter( startDate__lte = target.endDate ,
                                          endDate__gte = target.startDate )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
person = Company_Position_Person.objects.get(pk=...)
persons = Company_Position_Person.objects.exclude(startDate__gt=person.endDate, endDate__lt=person.startDate,pk=person.pk)
```